# can i connect my usb powered speakers to my phone charger?

Tags: usb, power-supply, power, speakers

I have got a 2.0 USB powered speakers which are supposed to be connected to the PC USB port. But that port creates noise in the speakers and is not very convenient. I have a phone charger of output dc 5v and 1A. Can I connect the speakers to the phone charger for power supply? Would it affect my speakers?

Comment: I had similar problem with noisy USB port and speakers. It turned out it was not the port itself that caused the noise. It was because of a wireless keyboard/mouse receiver plugged into another USB port.

Answer (score 3):

As a power-source you can use the charger. Whether it provides less noise remains to be seen. Many of those cheap chargers are electrically even more noisy than a PC power-supply.

Of course, this is assuming the speakers get the audio-signal through a separate cable. There also exist UBS speakers that get the audio via the USB.
If that is the case the only option is to try to find the USB port on the PC with the least noise.

Having a (powered) USB hub between the PC and the speakers might also help (in either of the scenarios outlined above), as in that case the power comes from the hub instead of the PC.